# Create a new google cloud instance using shut-down script

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am trying to use a shutdown-script to create a new instance from within the the instance that is shutting down now.

The script has three tasks,
1. creates an empty file
2. get the name of the new instance to be created
3. generates a name for the next new instance to be spawned
4. creates a new instance from within this instance with the name generated.

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

touch /home/ubuntu/newfile.txt

new_instance_name=$(curl http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/attributes/next_instance_name -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google")

next_instance_name="instance-"$(printf "%04d" $((${new_instance_name: -4}+1)))

gcloud beta compute --project=xxxxxxxxx instances create $new_instance_name --zone=us-central1-c --machine-type=f1-micro --subnet=default --network-tier=PREMIUM --metadata=next_instance_name=$next_instance_name --maintenance-policy=MIGRATE --service-account=XXXXXXXX-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com --scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform --image=image-1 --image-project=xxxxxxxx --boot-disk-size=10GB --boot-disk-type=pd-standard --boot-disk-device-name=$new_instance_name
```

This script is made executable using `chmod +x`and the file-name of the script is `/home/ubuntu/shtudown_script.sh`.he metadata `shutdown-script` for this instance is also `/home/ubuntu/shtudown_script.sh`.

All parts of the script runs fine when I run it manually from within the instance, so a new file is created and also a new instance is created when the current instance shuts-down.

But when it is invoked from API when I `stop` the instance, it only creates the file I create using `touch` command, but no new instance is created as before.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already had given my instance proper scope by giving the service account full access (which is a bad practice).

But the actual problem was solved when I reinstalled google-cloud-sdk using

```
sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk
```

When I was running those scripts before reinstalling `gcloud` by sshing into the instance it was using the `gcloud` command from preinstalled directory `/snap/bin/gcloud`. But when it runs from the startup or shutdown script, for some reason it can not get an access to the preinstalled `/snap/bin/` directory, and when I reinstall google cloud sdk using apt-get the `gcloud` command was being accessed from `/usr/bin/gcloud` which I think is accessible by the startup or shutdown script.

Answer (score 1):

So I was able to reproduce the behavior you described. I ran a bash script similar to the one you have provided as a shutdown script, and it would only create the empty file called "newfile.txt".

I then decided to append the output of the gcloud command to see what was happening. I had to tweak the bash script to fit my project. Here is the bash script I ran to copy the output to a file:

```
#!/bin/bash

touch /home/ubuntu/newfile.txt

gcloud beta compute --project=xxx instances create instance-6 --zone=us-central1-c --machine-type=f1-micro --subnet=default --maintenance-policy=MIGRATE --service-account=xxxx-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com --scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform --boot-disk-size=10GB --boot-disk-type=pd-standard --boot-disk-device-name=instance-6 > /var/output.txt 2>&1
```

The output I received was the following:

ERROR: (gcloud.beta.compute.instances.create) Could not fetch resource: - Insufficient Permission

This means that my default service account did not have the appropriate scopes to create the VM instance.

I then stopped my VM instance and edited the scopes to give the service account full access as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances#changeserviceaccountandscopes). Once I changed the scopes, I started the VM instance back up and then stopped it again. At this point, it successfully created the VM instance called "instance-6". I would not suggest giving the default service full access. I would suggest specifying which scopes it should have, but make sure that it has full access to Compute Engine if you want the shutdown script to work.

Answer (score 0):

If the shutdown script works when you stop the VM instance using the command:

$sudo shutdown -h now

And does not work when stopping the VM instance from the Cloud Console by pressing the “Stop” button, then I suspect this behavior is to be expected.

A shutdown script has a limited period of time to run when you stop a VM instance; however, this limit does not apply if you request the shutdown using the “sudo shutdown” command. You can read more about this behavior [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/shutdownscript#time_period).

If you would like to know more about the shutdown period, you can read about it [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/stopping-or-deleting-an-instance#delete_timeout).

Comment: I tried `$sudo shutdown -h now`. It produces same behavior, it can only create the empty file using touch command, but no new instance is created.